# Protruding "of" vs "with"

Tags: prepositions

I have a hard time precisely understanding the definitions of **"with"** and **"of"** in both Cambridge and and Collins dictionaries.

Shall I use "Her eyes protruded **with** vengeful stare" or "Her eyes protruded **of** vengeful stare"?

I understand that "with" gives me the cause of the action, but I think that "of" might tell me the cause ever better, whilst "with" sounds more like **"eyes"** and **"stare"** both protruded, you know... out of the water after a dive.

Thanks.

Comment: Protruded? really? http://imomus.com/feldman.jpg

Comment: Hahaha! That is funny. Well... I thought maybe metaphorically would do...?

Comment: She would certainly scare the bejeezus out of me if her eyes popped when vengeful... _Her vengeful stare had her eyes almost pop out of their sockets_

Comment: :)) I want to describe that she was really annoyed. "Wide open" it seems not enough...

Comment: I would forget about protruding eyes, and just say that she gave him a vengeful stare.

Comment: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/if+looks+could+kill

Comment: Thanks again, Mick! I will edit out the first part indeed. P.S.: @mplungjan I did not see your comment. Brilliant! Thanks!

Comment: For those who have been redirected to this topic by the search for "protruding of" vs " protruding with" I let them know that a quick Ngram search proved the nonexistence of such construction "protruding of" whatsoever. There are incidences of "protruding with", however they do not relate to this form of sentence I brought up here, which is, as the above users mentioned, ungrammatical in the first place.